# How can i add border to bottom of image?

Tags: java, android

I want to add a red border 50px height at image's bottom.

For ex:

[image]

```
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/meme_generated_image" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" 
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />


        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText android:id="@+id/edt_meme_bottom_txt1" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edt_text_bg" android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Write Text" android:padding="10dp" android:singleLine="true" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

my image loading from java file. can you please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the below code and add it below image

```
<View android:id="@+id/view" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp(as per your requirment)"
            android:background="your background color or boarder" />
```

**UPDATE**Replace your xml by below ml as you posted the code.

```
<LinearLayout 
  android:layout_width="match_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation = "vertical">

  <ImageView android:id="@+id/meme_generated_image" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" 
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <View android:id="@+id/view" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp(as per your requirment)"
            android:background="your background color or boarder" />

  </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText android:id="@+id/edt_meme_bottom_txt1" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edt_text_bg" android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Write Text" android:padding="10dp" android:singleLine="true" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

If you want to show the boader below image after loading the image then make the view visibility gone firstly and after image load done in image view then make the view visible through java code.

Hope it would help you.

Comment: Where do I put this code? Bottom of imageView ? @Sadiq

Comment: @IsmailAltunören place both image and view tag inside a linear layout of orientation vertical type. It will place view/boarder below image

Comment: i was update my question. my codes like that. can you please explain? my text getting from java file dynamically when i write to edit text

Comment: @IsmailAltunören I updated the code. Please have a look

Comment: can you message me from FB? my username "i.altunoren" please help. i just need only that not more.